# Advanced search with many to many in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have a list of real estates, which each real estate has some features. Then, I have 2 tables:

- real_estates, to store all real estates add by users.
- re_home_features, to store all default features, added by admin, like pool, closet, office, garden and a lot of features that the real estate can to have

The same real_estate can to have many features AND the same feature can to have many real estates. I created these models:

**real_estate.rb**

```
class RealEstate < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :real_estate_home_features
    has_many :re_home_features, as: :home_features, through: :real_estate_home_features, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**re_home_features.rb**

```
class ReHomeFeature < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :real_estate_home_features
    has_many :real_estates, through: :real_estate_home_features
end
```

**real_estate_home_feature.rb**

```
class RealEstateHomeFeature < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :real_estate
    belongs_to :re_home_feature
end
```

With this, the relation many to many is working fine.

I have a search to real estates with some parameters, like:

- Number of living rooms
- Number of bathrooms
- Sell price (min to max)
- Area total (min to max)
- Real estate code
- And a lot of other params

My search is like that:

**real_estates_controller.rb**

```
def search
    r = real_estates
    r = r.where(code: params['code']) if params['code'].present?
    r = r.where(city_name: params['city']) if params['city'].present?
    r = r.where(garage: params['garage']) if params['garage'].present?
    r = r.where(restrooms: params['restrooms']) if params['restrooms'].present?

    r = r.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)

    r
end
```

This search is working fine too. No problems with this, because all parameters are within the same table real_estates.

But now, the search is a little bit more complex. I have to search real estates with specific features. Example: I want all real estates, which has 4 restrooms, 2 cars in garage AND has **pool**.

In my example, a search in real estates with 4 restrooms and 2 cars returned to me 50 real estates, but only 15 of these real estates have pool.

How can I filter these 50 real estates to show only the records associated with the 'pool feature'?

I can't to verify in the view, because causes a wrong number per page. I think the filter must occur in the database query moment, just before the paginate.

I appreciate any help!

**environment**

```
rails -v: Rails 4.2.1
ruby -v: ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-linux]
so: Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
localhost database: MySQL (development)
server database: Postgres (production)
```

### EDIT 1

Based on @jvillian answer, I will change my controller, adding a JOIN in the query.

```
if params['home_features'].present? && params['home_features'].any?
    r = r.joins(:re_home_features).where(re_home_features: {id: params['home_features']}).distinct(:id)
end
```

In my tests, I had:

```
params['home_features'] = [1 , 2, 3]
```

I have 1 real estate which has these 3 features. But, in the view, I got the same site showed 3 times. If I added the distinct, the real estate is showed only once. BUT... If I change the params to:

```
params['home_features'] = [1 , 2, 3, 500]
```

I have no real estates with these 4 features, but the results are the same. 
Without distinct, the real estate are showed 3 times. With the dinstict, the real estate is showed once. The expected result is zero results, because I want real estates with all the selected features.

But I think we are almost there! I will provide some information about my models:

**table real_estates**

```
id | title      | description | code | city_name      | garage | ...
 7 | Your House | Awesome...  | 1234 | Rio de Janeiro | 4
```

**table re_home_features**

```
id | name
 1 | Pool
 2 | Garden
 3 | Tenis court
 4 | Closet
```

**table real_estate_home_features - association many to many**

```
id | real_estate_id | re_home_feature_id
 1 |              7 |                  1
 2 |              7 |                  2
 3 |              7 |                  3
```

If I run:

```
r = r.joins(:re_home_features).where(re_home_features: {id: [1,2,3,500]}).distinct(:id)
```

I got these query (rails console):

```
SELECT DISTINCT `real_estates`.* FROM `real_estates` INNER JOIN `real_estate_home_features` ON `real_estate_home_features`.`real_estate_id` = `real_estates`.`id` INNER JOIN `re_home_features` ON `re_home_features`.`id` = `real_estate_home_features`.`re_home_feature_id` WHERE `re_home_features`.`id` IN (1, 2, 3, 500)
```

And it returns 1 result. The real estate id 7. If I remove the distinct, I have 3 results: the same real estate, 3 times.

The expected is zero results. If `params['home_features'] = [1 , 2, 3]` I expect 1 result.

### EDIT 2

This join method works, but it returns like "OR" query. In my case, I need a join query with "AND". The query must be: "Return all real estates which has features 1 AND 2 AND 3".

Tks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is an "advanced search". Searching on joined models is covered in the guide under [12.1.4 Specifying Conditions on the Joined Tables](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-the-joined-tables). It would look something like:

```
real_estates.joins(:re_home_features).where(re_home_features: {feature_name: 'pool'})
```

Naturally, that's probably not going to exactly work because you don't tell us much about how to find the 'pool feature'. But, it should give you the right direction.

BTW, the reason this:

```
params['home_features'] = [1 , 2, 3, 500]
```

returns records that have `any` of the `home_features` is because it employs an 'or'. If you want `real_estates` with *all* `home_features`, then you want an 'and'. You can google around on that.

I think I would try something like:

```
def search

    r = real_estates.joins(:re_home_features)

    %i(
      code
      city_name
      garage
      restrooms
    ).each do |attribute|
      r = r.where(attribute => params[attribute]) unless params[attribute].blank?
    end

    params[:home_features].each do |home_feature_id|
      r = r.where(re_home_features: {id: home_feature_id})
    end unless params[:home_features].blank?

    r = r.uniq
    r = r.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
    r

end
```

NOTE: I changed `params[:city]` to `params[:city_name]` to make that first `each` iterator cleaner. You will need to change your view if you want to do it this way. If you don't want to do it this way, then you can go back to the non-iterator approach you already have.

This is not tested, so I'm not confident that it will work exactly as presented.

Comment: Hello @jvillian, thanks your answer! I will try right now!

Comment: Doesn' works, but is a good way. I have to go now, but after 2h I will to test more!

Comment: Yes. I guessed in my answer that it wouldn't work because you don't tell us enough about your `ReHomeFeature` model. Add some more detail to your question for a better answer.

Comment: Hey @jvillian! Your way is correct! I can see the results now. I will update my question with the results and to provide some more info about my models.

Comment: Great! Feel free to upvote/accept for future searchers.

Comment: I post the EDIT 1 with the result and more info about the models.

Comment: I added EDIT 2. Do you have an idea how to get these real estates?

Comment: Hello! My main research is around "join many to many", but I tried group and group concat with rails, trying to create another column with features comma separated, but I cant do a where in this new column. In all of my researches the results is the same (or) and not "and". I tried to group repeated real estates and joins the many to many association table (id features to left) doing a where with the features, but not works. I think other projects have to get results in association tables with and, but i dont found references in the web

Comment: Here's a hint. `r.joins(:re_home_features).where(re_home_features: {id: [1,2]}).uniq` does an `or`. `r.joins(:re_home_features).where(re_home_features: {id: 1}).where(re_home_features: {id: 2}).uniq` does an `and`. You probably don't want to type out all those `where` clauses, so use a loop on your `params[:home_features]` to properly construct your query.

Comment: Hey @jvillian! This solution, unfortunately doesn't works. It returns zero results. In my EDIT 1 I have a table `real_estate_home_features` . Note that this table has 1 real_estate (id 7) and 3 features (ids 1, 2 ,3). BUT, each association has 1 value in the column `re_home_feature_id`. If I run a query with: `1 == 1 AND 1 == 2 AND 1 == 3` in this register, it will return false and the register is not returned. The final query of your solution is: (next comment....)

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT `real_estates`.* FROM `real_estates` INNER JOIN `real_estate_home_features` ON `real_estate_home_features`.`real_estate_id` = `real_estates`.`id` INNER JOIN `re_home_features` ON `re_home_features`.`id` = `real_estate_home_features`.`re_home_feature_id` WHERE `re_home_features`.`id` = 1 AND `re_home_features`.`id` = 2